# Write vb.net for Excel without visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Is it possible to write VB.NET code to be used in an Excel spreadsheet without using Visual Studio? In other words, is there a built-in VB.NET editor for Excel that can be easily accessed like the built-in VBA editor? Or can I coerce the built-in VBA editor to allow me to write VB.NET code?

If the answer is no, do you know why Microsoft has not implemented this in Excel? It seems the ease of accessing the VBA editor is one of the reasons people still write new VBA code today. If Microsoft wants to be rid of VBA then why not make VB.NET more accessible in Excel? I'm not interested in speculation but instead any official word from Microsoft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some direct answers to the direct questions:

*is there a built-in VB.NET editor for Excel that can be easily accessed like the built-in VBA editor?*

Answer: No

*Or can I coerce the built-in VBA editor to allow me to write VB.NET code?*

Answer: No

*If the answer is no, do you know why Microsoft has not implemented this in Excel?*

Answer: since I'm not a Microsoft insider, No (but I could speculate...)

There are, of course, a variety of non-built in ways to interact with Excel.  But I'm sure you already know that.

Comment: Thank you for the direct answers.

Answer (score 2):

That's kind of a silly question.  The internal language for MS Excel currently happens to be VBA.  And frankly. VBA is pretty darn close to both VB6 as well as VB.Net, IMHO.  Certainly the two are more similar than, say C++, Java, Perl or any of a million other languages.

So why isn't doesn't Excel use VB.Net (or, for that matter, C#)?  Because Excel doesn't come with its own .Net runtime, and doesn't require you to have a .Net runtime to use it.

So why can't use use VB.Net (or C#) with Excep?  If *course* you can use them with Excel.  You can write a VB.Net program that reads and writes Excel spreadsheets, that invokes Excel functionality, that uses Excel as a datasource, etc etc etc.

So what more could you ask for ;)?

Comment: What more could I ask for? Exactly what I posted in the original question. Yes VBA and VB.NET are similar, but there are many things, such as initializing an array, that are more easily done in VB.net, not to mention access to a larger and better organized library of code.